# Steps to Deploying a MERN Application

Tags: deployment, mern, vercel, react-fullstack

I would like to deploy my full-stack MERN application. I can use either Vercel or Render to achieve this deployment. However, I do not know how to do this.

To start things off, here is the directory structure of my project.

```
inventoryManager
├── Client
│   ├── dist
│   │   └── output.css
│   ├── node_modules  
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── logo192.png
│   │   ├── logo512.png
│   │   ├── manifest.json
│   │   └── robots.txt
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── App.test.js
│   │   ├── Components
│   │   │   ├── AboutPage.js
│   │   │   ├── AddInventoryItem.js
│   │   │   ├── App.css
│   │   │   ├── App.js
│   │   │   ├── CategoryDelete.js
│   │   │   ├── CategoryToggle.js
│   │   │   ├── ControlPanel.js
│   │   │   ├── \<... other React components\>
│   │   ├── StateManager
│   │   │   ├── actionTypes.js
│   │   │   ├── dateReducer.js
│   │   │   ├── inventoryReducer.js
│   │   │   ├── requestState.js
│   │   │   ├── rootReducer.js
│   │   │   ├── services.js
│   │   │   └── thunk.js
│   │   ├── index.css
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── logo.svg
│   │   ├── normalize.css
│   │   ├── reportWebVitals.js
│   │   └── setupTests.js
│   └── tailwind.config.js
├── README.md
└── Server
├── Config
│   └── db.config.js
├── Models
│   ├── Category.js
│   └── InventoryItem.js
├── StarterData
│   ├── inventoryManager.categories.json
│   └── inventoryManager.inventoryitems.json
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── node_modules  
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── index.html
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── style.css
└── routes
├── InventoryItems.js
├── categories.js
└── index.js
```

Here are the files in the "Server" directory that may be of interest,

1. Server/bin/www.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('server:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '5000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

2. Server/app.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
require("dotenv").config();

// The main entry point for the Express backend. It sets up the application,
// defines middleware, connects to the MongoDB database, and configures the routes.

var inventoryRouter = require('./routes/InventoryItems');
var categoryRouter = require('./routes/categories');

var app = express();

// Enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) and allow requests from different origins.
// This prevents cross-site request forgery (CSRF) issues
app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/api/inventoryItems', inventoryRouter);
app.use('/api/categories', categoryRouter);

// Connect Express backend to (or create if first time) a remote MongoDB
// database called inventoryManager
mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB...'))
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB...');
        console.error(err);

        // Terminate the process with a non-zero exit code
        process.exit(1);
    });

module.exports = app;
```

Here are some relevant files for my "Client" directory.

1. Client/src/StateManager/services.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

// Service functions that make HTTP requests to the backend API endpoints using Axios.
// These functions provide an interface for interacting with the backend and performing
// CRUD operations on inventory items and categories.

const API_INVENTORY_ITEMS_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/inventoryItems';
const API_CATEGORIES_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/categories";

const getCategoryList = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(API_CATEGORIES_URL);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw handleRequestError(error);
    }
}

const deleteCategory = async (categoryID) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.delete(`${API_CATEGORIES_URL}/${categoryID}`);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw handleRequestError(error);
    }
}

const getInventoryList = async (categoryID) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${API_INVENTORY_ITEMS_URL}/fetchAllItems/${categoryID}`);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw handleRequestError(error);
    }
};

<... more HTTP request functions>

export default {
    getInventoryList,
    getCategoryList,
    deleteCategory,
    <... more>
};
```

2. Client/src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import rootReducer from './StateManager/rootReducer';
import App from './Components/App';
import "./index.css";
import "./normalize.css";
import "./Components/App.css";
import {ThemeProvider} from "@material-tailwind/react";

// The entry point of the React application. Overall, the code sets up the Redux store,
// renders the root component, and provides the necessary providers to enable Redux and
// the Material Tailwind theme in the application.

// This sets up the Redux store with the combined reducer.
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
});

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ThemeProvider>
                <App />
            </ThemeProvider>
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Now, given all this information, can you kindly show the steps/code changes I need to make in order to deploy this MERN application?

I can use either Vercel or Render, whichever make deployment easier.

So far, I have tried following the instructions listed here,

[how-to-deploy-mern-application-on-vercel](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-deploy-mern-application-on-vercel/)

However, after deploying the backend to Vercel, the deployment showed a 404 NOT Found error.

I also tried some instructions generated by ChatGPT on how to deploy using Vercel. But also to no avail.

I had a discussion with the teachers at my university and they said that Vercel might not be a suitable deployment choice for my application. Hence I am now considering Render.

If any of you can offer some step by step instructions on how I can deploy my application, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!!